# Better console output in HapiJS?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but I can't work out how to get better console output in HapiJS.

I am writing an API, and at the moment when there is an error it prints out.

> 150516/063815.663, [response], http://localhost:3000: post /users{} 500 (120ms)

And returns a response saying "there was an internal server error".

What do I need to change to see what that error output actually was?

Comment: You want the server to send the error in the response?

Comment: Please post the code for the handler where the internal server error takes place.

Comment: I want the console to print out the server error.  I'm not sure where the error is occurring because all it is giving me as a response is

```{
"statusCode": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "An internal server error occurred"
}```

and in the server console just printing out

```150516/063815.663, [response], http://localhost:3000: post /users {} 500 (120ms)```

Comment: I got that from the question. Could you post the code from your request handler for the path `http://localhost:3000/users` with HTTP method `POST`

Comment: It looks like you're using the Good plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/good) is that correct? If so, you can change the console reporter to include Error logs by adding `error: '*'` to the events hash

Comment: I'm not sure you get what I'm asking?  I had a bug in users but that is fixed now, but I had to fix it by trial and error / commenting out code etc.

What I am asking is how to get more verbose output in the server console when there are errors. 

More detailed errors with line numbers or at least file names, like you would with Angular or React.

Comment: Thanks @Clarkie, that looks like it might be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Good plugin](http://npmjs.com/package/good).

If so, you can change the console reporter to include Error logs by adding `error: '*'` to the events hash.

```
 reporters: [{
    reporter: require('good-console'),
    events: { log: '*', response: '*', error: '*' }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to log your Hapi.js project

1. Bucker -  [instance logger made by some hapi dude](https://github.com/nlf/bucker)
2. Good - [Good - hapijs plugin style](https://github.com/hapijs/good)
3. Winston - [probably one of the most common logger for node.js](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)